# How to import an SVG image and set the SVG width as the gliph advance?

Tags: svg, font-design, kerning, font-forge

I use Inkscape to draw one SVG file per letter and FontForge to integrate it. For this, I follow [this](https://fontforge.github.io/importexample.html) guide of FontForge documentation.

In the SVG file, I use the right border to indicate a character’s xMax:

[image: A character in Inkscape]

But when I import it to FontForge this one doesn’t care about the border and set’s an arbitrary (?) width:

[image: The same character in FontForge]

So, how can I define (with Inkscape) a vertical line which will be used by FontForge as the xMax? Or, how can I force FontForge to use SVG width as glyph width?

Comment: That’s not kerning, that’s the bearing of the glyph. Kerning are individual adjustments of the bearing depending on the preceding or following letter.

Comment: I am pretty certain @Wrzlprmft the correct term is *kerning*. At least, it’s the term FontForge use to define this functionnality (in Metric→Define right metric). You are probably wrong about the word “bearing”. Or, at least, FontForge users will beter understand me with a word used in the interface.

Comment: As I see in [this image](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/metrics.png) the bearing is a vertical value, when I want to manipulate a horizontal value (called “xMax” by this image). In my problem we can talk about xMax or kerning, or width, or advance but not about “kerning”. Is definitely the wrong concept.

Comment: In that image, the word *bearing* appears twice. And you might want to read the [context](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html) from which it was taken. Anyway, *advance* and *width* are also fine in your context.